# How to select and upload file in different server using JSON embedded in classic ASP?

Tags: json, rest, video, file-upload, asp-classic

I have the web page where you can select a video file and upload it in the same server (where the webpage is hosted). This function is coded in classic ASP and I am using freeASPUpload. This works fine.

```
 Set Upload = New FreeASPUpload
```

Now I am trying to change this system so that the video is uploaded in a different server. I am using JSON to creat a HTTP connection. Following is the code for the connection. My knowledge of REST is not that good so this code might not be correct.

```
Set xmlhttp = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.4.0")
xmlhttp.Open "PUT", "someurl.com", false
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "TOK:XXXX"
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json"
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Host", "www.test.com"
strJSON = "[{""MediPath"":""http:\/\/someurl.com\/<file_name>"",""MediaType"":""X""}]"
xmlhttp.send(strJSON)
```

I do not know how to integrate this code with my existing code. The main thing I want is the

```
<file_name>
```

that the user uses. I tried to look for documentations but none of them is what I wanted. Could you please point me in the right direction?

Comment: do you need to send file's content or only URL which points to your server?

Comment: I want to upload the video into the other server. So, it is the file's content.

Comment: ok, what api is provided by this other server? any doc?

Comment: Edgecast Web Services REST API. I have a PDF. Should I send it to you?

Comment: no, just read how they want to receive file, try to simulate it via ordinary forms, check what is actually send, then you will be able to reproduce it via asp/vb